# Lumen framework - add Queue from controller

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I try to add new job into queue from controller:

```
class SaveController extends Controller
{
public function save(Request $request, Queue $queue)
{
    $q = $queue->pushOn('getSent', new \App\Jobs\SomeJobs('hello'));
    return $q;
}
}
```

but i catch error:

```
lumen.ERROR: exception 'Illuminate\Container\BindingResolutionException' with message 'Target [Illuminate\Queue\Queue] is not instantiable.' in /var/www/lumenlocal/lumen/vendor/illuminate/container/Container.php:785
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need use contract:

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\Queue;
```

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/lumen/add-queue-from-controller

Answer (score 0):

Quoted from [Lumen docs](http://lumen.laravel.com/docs/queues)

> Note: If you intend to use the Queue facade, be sure to uncomment the
>   `$app->withFacades()` call in your `bootstrap/app.php` file.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit tricky with Lumen because the support is not the same as Laravel right now. You could use.

$data = ['hello'];

Queue::pushOn('getSent', '\App\Jobs\SomeJobs', $data);

This should create a record in the jobs table which would be:

{"job":"\App\Jobs\SomeJobs","data":['hello']} - or similar.

Then just make sure when you call the worker process that you specify which queue to use which in this case is 'getSent'